# HTML, CSS: Extra space in the body

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website but for some reason there is extra space in the body width. I used `margin-left: 0` but that didn't help.

Result of my code: https://chezzles-shreyas1703.c9users.io/index.html

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you be more specific with what your issue is? where is this extra space you are seeing - with the link you posted the body looks fine to me

Comment: Try and scroll left when the width of the browser is less than 850px. The body has extra space when

Comment: As-is, this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). Please update it to include a [mcve].

Comment: `main-content` should be `margin: 0 20px 0 0;` not `margin: 0 20px;`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `margin-left` to `5%` or `20px`. Currently it set to `13%`.

```
.main-content {
margin-left: 5%;
}
```

Or

```
.main-content {
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are saying I am pretty sure your issue lies with the `margin-left` property on your `.main-container` class

```
.main-content {
   margin-left: 13%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> At media screen of max-width : 850px, you have given your section a
>   width of 100% change it to max-width.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px)
section {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```